# Converting Ai Graphic Styles to Photoshop patterns

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, swatches, graphic-styles

Is there anyway to convert Ai graphic styles for use in Photoshop as a pattern? or swatch?

Answer (score 2):

Steps

1. Create a new File in Photoshop(It should be small (in terms of height x width). Image you are creating here will duplicate itself to form your pattern in the later stage)
2. Drag and Drop your Illustrator pattern in photoshop( or you can import your .ai file ) and re-size it according to the Photoshop file size if needed and Hide or Delete your background image
3. Now Choose **Edit > Define Pattern**. Enter a name for the pattern in the Pattern Name dialog box.Now you pattern is created
4. To apply this pattern to your document Create a new layer, GO to **Edit > Fill**. Now, In the Fill dialog box, select Pattern from the dropdown, find the pattern you’ve just created in Custom Pattern and click OK.

DONE!